Django admin Many-to-Many field in inlinetabular admin doesn't work for both sides of relaion
Question
How can I integrate m2m fields into modelAdmin, considering that this field has through argument and that I can't change the DB? Or how can I use inlinetabular admin with add more button?
Description
I have Django 5 app working with legacy DB (PostgreSQL).
This DB has 3 tables described by models bellow:
class EmployeeLinkRole(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        "Employees",
        models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column="Employee_ID",
        primary_key=True,
    ) 
    role = models.ForeignKey("Roles", models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="Role_ID")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Timesheet"."Employee_Link_Role'
        unique_together = (("employee", "role"),)


class Employees(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.BigAutoField(
        db_column="Employee_ID", primary_key=True
    )
    employee_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=500, db_column="Employee_Name", blank=True, null=True
    )
    role = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Roles",
        through=EmployeeLinkRole,
        through_fields=("employee", "role"),
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Timesheet"."Employees'


class Roles(models.Model):
    role_id = models.AutoField(db_column="Role_ID", primary_key=True)
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_column="Role_Name")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Timesheet"."Roles'

My admin code:
class RoleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Employees.role.through


@admin.register(Employees)
class EmployeesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        RoleInline,
    ]


@admin.register(Roles)
class RolesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (RoleInline,)

Issue
The issue I am facing: inline model is show and work fine in both Employees and Roles models.
However I can't make it to show "Add more" button in Employees admin.
In Employees

In Roles

Expectations
I need an "add more" button in my inlinetabular admin in both Employees and Roles admins.
What I checked
I've spent loads of time searching for a solution, including talking to GPT.
I've found out that the block with the button has "display: none"  attribute.
I've already tried to add extra = 4 and max_num = 10 attributes to inline admin.
I've already tried to redefine save and has_changed methods of ModelAdmin class.
I've already tried to collectstatic.

Well after digging into the source code I found out that my max_num value was forcibly redefined to 1 as I had employee field set as primary key in my 'through' table.
The code that redefines it is located in forms/models.py -> inlineformset_factory()
class EmployeeLinkRole(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        ...
        primary_key=True,
    ) 
    ....

As far as I see, I have no other way but to harmonize the change in DB.
Now I have composite key that is not supported by Django. And I need an id field to be added.
